# Angular ESLint Error Parameter key required

Tags: angularjs, angular, eslint

I am trying to download a file using below Angular Code but I keep on getting **Parameter "key" required**

```
const headerValues = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': contentType!, 'Accept': contentType! });

this.http
  .get(`${this.resourceUrl}/${id}/download`, { headers: headerValues })
  .subscribe(data => {
    const blob = new Blob([data as BlobPart], { type: contentType });
    const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(downloadUrl);

    console.log('Alert :: Done ');

  }, (error) => {
    console.log('Alert :: error: ' + error);

  }, () => {
    console.log("this is the finally block");
  });
```

It keeps on printing Alert :: label error   Error: Parameter "key" required. Couldn't find anything relevant. This error is being thrown by TranslateService but I couldn't figure out why

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution to the issue. Default responseType is blob | undefined. Adding blob responseType in this.http.get() options parameter resolved the issue.

```
this.http.get(`${this.resourceUrl}/${id}/download`, { headers, responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe((res) => {
        const file = new Blob([res as BlobPart], {
          type: contentType,
        });
```